# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, soap

A client developed in Java using JDK 1.6. I am consuming API in the java code. Whenever I hit this API from soapui or from JDK 1.7 it is working perfectly fine but when I tried to hit this API using JDK 1.6, it is returning the error.
`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

I have tried by developing client using WSDL and using HTTPSURLConnection, with both mechanism, I am getting the same error. It seems there is nothing wrong with the code. I am unable to find out the way for the resolution.

Wireshark Result:
When I ran the jar from JDK 1.7, I can see the result in Wireshark, the protocol is TSLv1 but when I tried to run the jar from 1.6, the protocol has been changed to SSLv2.
Is it possible to change protocol in the code or on the system where we are calling jar?

Here is my code:

```java
public String myFun(String sender) throws IOException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException{
   
    
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    TrustManager[] trustManager = getTrustManager();
    sslContext.init(null, trustManager, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    try{
            String inquiryRequest = inquiryRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:v5=\"http://xxxxxxx\">\n" 
                    +"<soapenv:Header>\n" 
                    +"</soapenv:Header>\n" 
                    +"<soapenv:Body>\n" 
                    +"<v5:single.smsReq>\n" 
                    +"<sender>"+sender+"</sender>\n" 
                    +"</v5:single.smsReq>\n" 
                    +"</soapenv:Body>\n" 
                    +"</soapenv:Envelope>";
            
            URL url =new URL ("https://xxxx:xx/xx");
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/xml");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic xxx");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(inquiryRequest);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                conn.disconnect();
        
            return response.toString();
                 
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    } 
    
}
private TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
    TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String t) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String t) {
        }
    }
    };
    return certs;
}
```

Comment: Seems like its an URL path issue, by the way add your URL and connection information if possible.

Comment: If it is a path issue then why it is working fine with JDK 1.7?

Comment: Added my code @RedBoy

Answer (score 0):

In SSLContext you can setup your own SSlContext TSLv1 or SSLv2 then call sslContext.init with trusted certificates. And, add it to your HttpsURLConnection as the DefaultSSLSocketFactory.

```
System.setProperty ("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
TrustManager[] trustManager = getTrustManager();
sslContext.init(null, trustManager, new SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

HostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostNameVerifier);
```

Comment: I added it but getting the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSLv2 SSLContext not available

Comment: tried both TLSv1 and SSL but the error is the same "connection reset". In the Wireshark, I can see protocol is SSLv2 against both the request.

Comment: @Touqeer Add the hostname verifier and added jsse.enableSNIExtension as false.

Comment: getting the same error "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" after adding the jsse.enableSNIExtension as false and hostname verified